# How to use jQuery plugin localStorage to store numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I am new to Jquery and JavaScript. I am trying to store data using Jquery "onsubmit" function and the Jquery plugin localStorage. I have read about how to store data using the localStorage.setItem("name", "Jack");
I am trying to store numbers or integer into the localStorage. When the user clicks the submit button, after selecting one of the options, the localStorage should add the new value to the old like localStorage.setItem(selectedValue) + localStorage.setItem(selectedValue);. This way selectedValue keeps increasing by the selection the user selects.

```
var selectedValue=0;
 var sum = $('.gradept').on('change', function () {
     selectedValue = $('.gradept option:selected').val();
     if(selectedValue == 'A1')
     { selectedValue = 1}
     else if(selectedValue == 'B2')
     { selectedValue = 2}
     else if(selectedValue == 'B3')
     { selectedValue = 3}
     else if(selectedValue == 'C4')
     { selectedValue = 4}
     else if(selectedValue == 'C5')
     { selectedValue = 5}
     else if(selectedValue == 'C6')
     { selectedValue = 6}
     else if(selectedValue == 'D7')
     { selectedValue = 7}
     else if(selectedValue == 'E8')
     { selectedValue = 8}
     else if(selectedValue == 'F9')
     { selectedValue = 9}
     $("#go").val(selectedValue);
   console.log("total" ,selectedValue);
});
```

This what i have tried

```
$('.inline').on('submit', function(){
    localStorge.setItem("grade",selectedValue)+ localStorge.setItem("grade",selectedValue);
       console.log("The total is", localStorage.getItem("grade"));
    })
```

Comment: You have answered your own question. Have you tried it out?

Comment: @Terry Yes i have but i am not able to accomplish summing or adding number using the localStorage

Comment: By "not able to accomplish", what kind of difficulties are you running into? You can share what you've tried by updating your question.

Comment: @Terry I have updated my question. I am i making sense now?

Comment: One more thing to add in... what storage plugin are you using, can you link to it, I've gotten everything else working I just need to find out which one you're using to give an example

Comment: @nfnneil I am using https://github.com/julien-maurel/jQuery-Storage-API

Comment: @nfnneil You can also recommend a localStorage that i can try. This is the first time i am trying this.

Comment: Posted an example.

Comment: @nfnneil thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that on the homepage of the extension given, it says it is no longer being worked on.  So, I followed the link to the new github.  It is JavaScript storage. Then, when I looked at your code, I realized you were doing a lot more work then you had to.  I used regex to simplify your if then statements.  Then, I used the storage.set and storage.get methods.

The link to the non-depreciated github:

https://github.com/julien-maurel/js-storage

```
<select name="yay" id="gradept">
    <option value="A1">1</option>
    <option value="B2">2</option>
    <option value="C3">3</option>
    <option value="D4">4</option>
    <option value="E5">5</option>
    <option value="F6">6</option>
    <option value="G7">7</option>
    <option value="H8">8</option>
    <option value="I9">9</option>
    <option value="J0">0</option>
</select>

<button class="inline">test</button>

<br />

    <button class="getStorage">Click me to get item from storage!</button>
<div id='sendInformationHere'></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js-storage-master/js.storage.min.js"></script>

<script>
storage=Storages.localStorage;

$(function() {
    $('.inline').on('click', function(){
        value = Number($('#gradept').val().replace(/\D/g,''));
        storage.set("grade",value);     
    });

    $(".getStorage").on('click', function() {
        $("#sendInformationHere").html(storage.get("grade"));
    });
});

</script>
```